# Check whether field exists in SQLite without fetching them all

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am writing a database abstraction layer that also abstracts some of the different query types. One of them is called "field_exists" - its purpose should be pretty self-explanatory.

And I want to implement that for SQLite.

The problem I am having is that I need to use one query that either returns a row confirming that the field exists or none if it doesn't. Thus, I cannot use the PRAGMA approach.

So, what query can I use to check whether a field exists in SQLite, that fulfills the above criteria?

**EDIT:** I should add that the query needs to be able to run in PHP code (using PDO).

Also, the query should look something like this (which only works with MySQL):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table LIKE 'field'
```

Comment: SQLite doesn't have anything analogous to SHOW COLUMNS. You're not going to be able to do a raw query here. The solution is going to amount to some sort of query + grep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to select a field that doesn't exist will return an exception, then you can catch it and return nothing.

Comment: Sometimes, the simple things do it. I now changed the code so that this approach will be used across all the different database types. It is the most consistent and pretty easy, too.

Comment: That is bad practice, Exceptions are expensive

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.schema TABLENAME` command. It will tell you the command that was issued to create the table. For more info chekcout the SQLite [command shell documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).

If you don't have access to the sqlite command line, you can always query the sqlite_master table. Let's say you want to know the command used to create the table MyTable. You'd issue this:

```
select sql from sqlite_master where name='MyTable';
```

This then gives you the sql command that was used to create the table. Then just grep through that output and see if the column you're looking for is in the command used to create the table.

UPDATE 2:

Actually better than the sql I posted above, you can use this:

```
PRAGMA table_info(*table_name*)
```

This will show you all the columns in a given table along with their types and other info.

Comment: That still gives me a result, though, if the table does not have the field I am asking for. Also, I am running this from PHP, so command-line SQLite does not help. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Edited my answer to address your comment.